Should I let the client know that the documents for existing projects are not good at all?
I am working with a client. The team members are great. Client is good. When I joined the project, I had some knowledge transfer (KT) sessions. Although some of the KTs were good, it wasnt sufficient. Most of the codes were 2-3 years old, and even the developers who had written the codes didn't remember exactly what they were doing (which is normal). Even the architecture diagrams of some projects are either missing or incomplete.
So, it becomes difficult to understand some critical aspect of the code pieces. Most of the team members said that they have received good KTs, but they always ask for multiple helps when actually working in the code pieces. Even one person, who literally said that the KT sessions were the best, is unwilling to take up work that are related to existing codes.
I informed this problem of lack of documents to my team lead and manager, but I haven't informed the client. Should I ?
P.S - We report directly to the client during standup/scrum calls. All daily updates are given directly to the client by individuals. Only the team lead is available in the calls, but he too is assigned similar work. Manager never joins the calls, unless s/he is requested by the client. Also, client has no clue that KTs are not all good. He thinks that his team provides the best KT in the company.


but I haven't informed the client. Should I ?

Definitely not !!
Doing that, you destroy two things:

your relationship with your company;
the relationship between the companies.

We cannot even guess what the effects of that would be, but they would definitely not be nice for anyone.
As a programmer, you should have no direct communication to the customer. And even though you might have it, keep the information transfer to the minimum necessary. And especially do not tell what is / happens wrong in your company.
As a minimum, understand the meaning of the idiom "wash one's dirty laundry in public" and why you should not do it.

As a side note, the situation you describe is pretty much the situation of most companies. The good thing you can do, if you want to be better than the others, is to start improving that documentation yourself.

EDIT: While your question is strange (according to my experience), it is still good that you asked the question, rather to act and create trouble. Your best bet for good answers are actually your team lead and your manager. When in doubt, ask them. Clarify everything that is ambiguous to you. And then follow their decision.
It is best if the decisions are made written. The easiest way to do that, after discussions create a short meeting minutes, describing the questions, the answers and the decisions, and who said what (especially for the answers and for the decisions). Then share the notes with them. E-mail is OK. Make sure to have an archive of these meeting minutes - just in case, to be safe.

EDIT
Metaphorically, in the context of this question (disclosing something to the client), you have to consider everyone in your company as friends, and everyone in the client company as "enemies". Since they are "enemies", they receive the minimum information required, and not more.

We report directly to the client during standup/scrum calls. All daily updates are given directly to the client by individuals. Only the team lead is available in the calls, but he too is assigned similar work. Manager never joins the calls, unless s/he is requested by the client.  That was the reason of my confusion.

Also, client has no clue that KTs are not all good. He thinks that his team provides the best KT in the company.

Unusual, but why not. however, you report only the minimum necessary according to the assigned tasks. You do not give for free information which should not be available even for sale.

"Also, client has no clue that KTs are not all good." - And why should they? They are just the client. They need to care about what they receive (mostly), and not how it is done (although not really entirely true).

I assume the | in "|enemies" is a typo?

@jimmyT. Weird typo to get though, it is a large stretch between '|' and most other keys... Is virolino secretly a spider? https://xkcd.com/1530/???

I completely disagree with "As a programmer, you should have no direct communication to the customer".  Someone else should be managing the relationship but there are times when the best or even the only way to really understand what the customer needs is to actually talk directly to them.

imho this highly depends on the client relationship; in some cases you'll be more part of the team on the client than of your contractor team and are basically just a resource "on loan" and thus, yes, should report every type of potential blocker issue to your client, in others you deliver products for the client and then the client indeed shouldn't hear from you about any internal issues. OP seems to be somewhat in the middle of these two.

@DaveG I believe the statement is for the generic programmer, who tends to have much weaker business background and training, and will typically focus on things that are actually irrelevant to the client. Anyone that's technical and has proper Project Management training will already know why that statement is said. How often do programmers focus on some optimization of architecture/framework/programming language where the end-result is some single digit percentage that nobody would even notice?

@JimmyT.: Correct assumption. Tnx.

@Questor: Funny comic. But as a matter of fact, the keys for the quotation mark and for the vertical bar are just next to each other.

@DaveG: And hence "should not" and not "must not". And please notice that I did not claim "no communication at all", but only "no direct independent communication" - as support for the actual contact person.

@Nelson I think your example of developers focusing on things that are irrelevant to the customer is exactly why devs need customer contact.  In my career I found that actually talking to the customer often cleared away fog that had been introduced by layers of "product management".  It also depends on company size.  I worked most of my career at smaller and mid-sized companies where there weren't any "generic programmers" who were working on things irrelevant to clients.

@virolino They are pretty far appart <gasp... you are a spider>


I informed this problem of lack of documents to my team lead and manager, but I haven't informed the client. Should I ?

You've informed your managers, and it's now up to them if, when and how they communicate this to the end client. Going over their heads and talking to the client directly is a very bad idea, and could potentially end up getting you fired.
Just make sure that you have a record of the fact you've warned people internally about this (to cover your arse down the line), and leave it at that.
If you want to try and do more to deal with the actual problem, then the solution is to improve the documentation - so you can volunteer to do that. But whether or not that's considered a priority is not up to you.

Also, client has no clue that KTs are not all good. He thinks that his team provides the best KT in the company.

We report directly to the client during standup/scrum calls. All daily updates are given directly to the client by individuals. Only the team lead is available in the calls, but he too is assigned similar work. Manager never joins the calls, unless s/he is requested by the client. That was the reason of my confusion

@Skumar talk to your team lead and manager, and ask them how they want to handle this. If the client thinks things are great and they're not then there could be some considerable fallout from that (especially if this is an issue that's been getting ignored or lied about for a long time), so it needs to done carefully - and you don't want to be the one getting blamed if that conversation goes badly.

If you are uncertain what your client relationship is and what type of information you should directly communicate to your client then simply:
Ask your manager
What you should and shouldn't directly tell your client highly depends on the client relationship your own company has with the client. If your company just delivers a project to the client, they might want to keep internals under wraps (and it might just scare and annoy the client if you tell them).
If however, you are a resource on loan to your client and in practice a member of the client team first and foremost regarding any practical project topics, the client likely should hear this - but your manager might already have taken care. Either way, since it seems you are unsure of your exact role and the preferred flow of information: clarify explicitly with your manager!
In situations like these: Either you have a clear understanding of your role and the preferred flow of information or you clarify with your direct manager before anything else.

It is true that documentation generally is beneficial, it save time and reduce the ramp up period.
But inadequate documentation seems to be an industry standard and not really because people are lazy, it is more because software change faster than it seems and it take a lot of time to keep the documentation updated.

will you redo all the print screen because a new button have been added to the UI? Is some pages will be missed if there a lot of page to update? Will you redo it in the following sprint if there is another UI change?

If you change the behavior, how do you know all place in the documentation related to this behavior modification?

Some organizations have a high turn over, the developers may not know the whole application so they cannot write down the behavior even if they would like.


Personally, raising the point the documentation is bad look like the person is new to the industry, I will brush it off.
There are some folks in the industry that push living documentation by various method like unit tests and infrastructure as code. I attest great results because when something change, something break, so you know it is almost all up to date.
Finally, there is exception like everything. Documentation is required at some organizations to keep their certifications, there is a "Change Advisor Board" in place, etc. but my experience is documentation rot fast, it take a considerable effort to keep update.
Happy coding!

I know that bad documentation is a industrial problem. My concern was bcoz client thinks that all docs and KTs are given properly. So, everyone is well aware of everything, what any code does. But, that's not correct.

So often an organization state "we are good at X", where X can be code quality, communication, documentation, whatever and you have see others places better. My experience is better to keep critics to yourself and flow with it because change is hard and slow. There is high probably that a loud mouth or disgruntled coworker already told them.

Also note that "good" documentation is pretty subjective. And even the ideals differ - some prefer a full handbook others want the code to be so self-explanatory that only minimal external documentation is needed and the effectiveness in any case depends on the existing domain and technical knowledge of the reader and the target audience. However, if OP were not in this unclear client relationship, I'd say it rarely hurts to point out something is amiss from your pov, but ideally be specific, because perhaps there is a resource/context you are simply unaware of.

I would raise it with your managers and leave them to make the decision. BUT the important thing is how you raise it with your manager. Just telling them the docs are "no good at all" probably won't achieve much, as it doesn't tell them the concrete problems that this will cause..
When you tell your manager about the docs problems, point to concrete issues this has caused:

highlight any confusion they have caused
explain how much time the team are having to "waste" clarifying stuff that isn't well explained in the docs
highlight any mistakes that the customer has made because of the docs

You say that the customer thinks the knowledge transfer is good, which makes me wonder if the docs are actually causing any problems so far.  Engineers are generally unhappy with existing docs (and code) and only see the deficiencies and not when they are "good enough" to meet a customer's need

In real life, documents, rarely actually get updated (except maybe at the beginning of the project). Almost never at a properly mature level.

@mattfreake The team lead is not completely aware of 2 projects. One new team member is not willing to take work on existing project. I always have to go and ask the developer (who developed those) for complicated codes. And problem is, this developer is quitting soon.

Bad documentation?
I've got 40 years experience in this field.  From where I started in COBOL (don't laugh, your bank is probably still running COBOL) to the latest hot technology there is one common fact about documentation - after the first release of a system the documentation gradually becomes more and more "bad" (incomplete, out-of-date, wron0, etc.) the further from "reality" is that documentation.
It's our job as developers to actually understand the code instead of depending on documents that may or may not be correct.
Do not talk to the company about the documentation.  The team you're working with already knows this.  There is no upside for you.
Talk to your manager.  Have some specific questions (not complaints) about whatever is happening in the system.  See if there is a SME (subject matter expert) that can answer your questions.
Good luck!!
